# HTML DOM parsing problem

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I'm trying to parse html with the simple html dom.

Using this example

```
<h3>
<span class="time">19:00
</span> 
<a href="/simpsons">The Simpsons</a> 
</h3>
<p class="synopsis">Fat Man and Little Boy: When Bart becomes a t-shirt mogul, and the household's main breadwinner, Homer worries that he no longer has a role in the family.
</p>
<a class="link" href="/simpsons/watch">Watch Now</a> 



<h3>
<span class="time">20:00</span> 
24
</h3>
<p class="synopsis">Emotions run high as the harrowing day climaxes with resolute President Taylor closing in on a world-changing peace treaty. 
</p>


<h3>
<span class="time">21:00</span> 
<a href="/lost">Lost</a> 
</h3>
<p class="synopsis">Pseudo-Locke tries to destroy the island and all of its inhabitants, while Jack attempts to stop him. 
</p>
<a class="link" href="/lost/watch">Watch Now</a>
```

How can I grab

1. The Time
2. The Title
3. The Synopsis
4. The Link (if it exists)

As you can see the source entries are inconsistant, sometimes the title is wrapped in anchor and may not always have a Watch Now link.

Comment: not on 6 questions.. if it was 50 or something there is a problem.

Comment: Sorry, should have done it before. I normally just leave a comment.

Comment: @Madmartigan: Answers should be accepted if they, well, answer the question. This way credit is given where it's due and it's taken off the 'Unanswered Questions' list. If you view @jamjam's questions, most of them have accurate answers.

Comment: What have you tried already? Why do the examples at the SimpleHtmlDom dont answer your question? Did you search SO before asking your question? Why not? This question sounds like "I cannot be bothered to figure it out myself. Now gimme teh codez" to me.

Comment: Just saw your comment Gordon. I'm not asking this question because I couldn't "bothered", I'm real stuck. People on this forum have helped me out many times before. But I have taking your suggestion and I'm currently reading SimpleHtmlDom site.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like valid XHTML, so it should also be valid XML.  Just traverse it like normal XML.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php